# How to change the behaviour of kube-scheduler in EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, kube-scheduler

I am new at Kubernetes and completely new to setting it up in `EKS`.

I am trying to achieve sharing of `GPU` between multiple pods, but for that going through few of the documents and articles, I found out I should update the `kube-scheduler configuration` with parameters which will then allow me the make the necessary changes for enabling sharing of `GPU` between pods.

**Question**

How do I update the `kube-scheduler` configuration in `EKS`. If update for the configuration is not possible, is there some other way I can setup `kube-scheduler` for only those pods which require `GPU` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a custom kubescheduler, and for your pods to be able to specify whether they want to use the default or the custom scheduler.

Kubernetes supports this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/ -- basically, create a .yaml file, run `kubectl create -f` on it, and you should see your scheduler. You'll want to run it in the `kube-system` namespace, and give it a unique name (so your pods have a way of saying which scheduler they want).

I haven't done this in EKS myself, but would be very surprised if you couldn't run a custom scheduler in EKS. Moreover, this aws blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/virtual-gpu-device-plugin-for-inference-workload-in-kubernetes/ , which sounds similar to what you're looking for, seems like it would require a custom scheduler.

Comment: Hy @Paschen. Thank you for your response, I will try it out and update you my findings here.

Comment: @dempti So how did it go? Did the answer provided helped?

Comment: Hy @Marcin. Yes the solution helped me.

Comment: @dempti If so, then the answer should be accepted.