# K8S Cluster level topology spread

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, topology

EKS 1.23

Trying to set default podTopologySpead on cluster level. Using the suggested config from k8s documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#cluster-level-default-constraints :

```
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration

profiles:
  - schedulerName: default-scheduler
    pluginConfig:
      - name: PodTopologySpread
        args:
          defaultConstraints:
            - maxSkew: 1
              topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
              whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
          defaultingType: List
```

when applying I get the following error:

```
➜ kubectl apply -f ./topology-test
error: unable to recognize "./topology-test": no matches for kind "KubeSchedulerConfiguration" in version "kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta3"
```

Also tried to change api version to `v1beta1`, `v1beta2`,`v1alpha1`,`v1`.

another question regarding it: isn't this configuration requires namespace mention?

Answer (score 1):

> You can customize the behavior of the kube-scheduler by writing a
> configuration file and passing its path as a command line argument.

You need to pass configuration as an argument to the kube-scheduler like `kube-scheduler --config <filename>`.

Additionally you can run `kubectl api-versions` to print the supported API versions on the server.

Please refer the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/) for details

**UPDATE**

As it seems, you cannot update the `default-scheduler` in EKS, you will need to create a `custom scheduler` in EKS and then pass in your `KubeSchedulerConfiguration` within the new scheduler, a sample YAML for it can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/#define-a-kubernetes-deployment-for-the-scheduler).

Also check this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442233/how-to-change-the-behaviour-of-kube-scheduler-in-eks) about `kube-scheduler in EKS`

Comment: From where should the command `kube-scheduler --config <filename>` be ran? my local machine doesn't recognize `kube-scheduler` command.

Comment: this isn't a CLI command, you need to pass in this config to the `kube-scheduler` executable, if you cannot update the default scheduler, you create a [custom scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/#define-a-kubernetes-deployment-for-the-scheduler) as well

Comment: Thanks, so how do I "pass in this config"?

Comment: I am using EKS1.23. What is the procedure in order to make this configuration applied to the kube-scheduler?

Comment: I don't think you can update the default scheduler in EKS (by passing the config), you need to create a [custom scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/) and then while creation you can pass in the `kube-scheduler --config <filename>` option. See this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442233/how-to-change-the-behaviour-of-kube-scheduler-in-eks) as well